# Mejorar tiempo de esta función para hallar el siguiente mayor número entero con los mismos dígitos

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Hice una función que dado un número `n`, toma sus dígitos y busca el siguiente número mayor que él que se puede formar con ellos.

Ejemplos:

```
n = 513  => debe devolver 531 
n = 9219 => debe devolver 9291  
n = 123  => debe devolver 132
```

De no poder formarse el número, la función debe regresar `-1`. El problema es que esta función sencilla es fuerza bruta y no pasa el test de velocidad, pues lo que hace es incrementar el número en `1` hasta que encuentra un numero que tiene los mismos dígitos y en caso de un número muy grande debe hacer muchas comparaciones en las cual:

- transforma el número
- lo recorre
- lo ordena
- etc...

¿Cómo se puede mejorar la parte en la que compara si los dígitos del número son los mismos que los del número `n`?

```js
function nextBigger(n) {
    const digitos = `${n}`.split('').sort((a, b) => a - b).join('');
    if (n == mayorPosible) return -1
    else {
        do {
            n++
        } while (digitosNumero(n) != digitos)
    }
    return n
}

function mayorPosible(n) {
    return Number(`${n}`.split('').sort((a, b) => b - a).join(''))
}

function digitosNumero(n) {
    return `${n}`.split('').sort((a, b) => a - b).join('')
}

console.log(nextBigger(513));
console.log(nextBigger(2063));
console.log(nextBigger(1497));
```

Comment: en el caso del 9219 el siguiente no debera ser 9291?, lo mismo para el
123 el siguiente no es el 132?

Comment: @erika_chan si tienes razon fueron ejemplos rapidos lo corrijo

Comment: Disculpa ¿En que pagina haces esos test de velocidad? Y esta vez no voy a responder, quiero ver las respuestas de otros usuarios.

Comment: @the-breaker en codewars.com te hace test a tu funcion y pasas o no el de velocidad.. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función debería ser algo como esto, la mecánica no es un invento mío, sino de [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-next-greater-number-set-digits/), la implementación si es mía, y hay muchas cosas que se pueden mejorar:

```js
function nextBigger(num) {

    let it = [Infinity,...`${num}`];

    for (let i = it.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (it[i] < it[i + 1]) {
            let temp = it[i];
            let sub = it.slice(i + 1, it.length).sort((a, b) => a - b);

            let idxSwap = i;

            for (let j = 0; j < sub.length; j++) {
                if (sub[j] > temp) {
                    idxSwap = it.lastIndexOf(sub[j]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            it[i] = it[idxSwap];
            it[idxSwap] = temp;
            it = [...it.slice(0, i + 1), ...it.slice(i + 1, it.length).sort((a, b) => a - b)];
            return +it.slice(1,it.length).join("");
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

console.log(144, nextBigger(144));
console.log(12, nextBigger(12));
console.log(736, nextBigger(736));
console.log(27,nextBigger(27));
console.log(17,nextBigger(17));
console.log(46, nextBigger(46));
console.log(160, nextBigger(160));
console.log(50904, nextBigger(50904));
console.log(9999, nextBigger(9999));
console.log(513, nextBigger(513));
console.log(9219,nextBigger(9219));
console.log(123,nextBigger(123));
console.log(20141, nextBigger(20141));
console.log(1308686, nextBigger(1308686));
console.log(1234567890, nextBigger(1234567890));
console.log(59884848459853,nextBigger(59884848459853));
```

Agregué el `infinity` siempre como primer elemento porque no encontré una forma mejor de resolver el tema de checkear si hay que cambiar de lugar el primer elemento. El `lastIndexOf` no parece ser la mejor forma de buscar el indice.

Los pasos deberían ser:

- Buscamos desde la izquierda hasta encontrar el primer digito que sea menor que el anterior, si el input es 534976 paramos en 4 porque 4 es menor que el siguiente que sería 9, si no encontramos ese número, retornamos -1.
- Luego, buscamos en los digitos que quedaron a la derecha el menor digito mayor que el que encontramos al principio, 976 en el ejemplo y el menor pero mayor a 4 es 6.
- Intercambiamos las posiciones de esos números quedando 536974 en el ejemplo.
- Desde la posición del primer digito encontrado al final lo ordenamos de de menor a mayor y ya estaría.

Comment: Emmeus hasta ahora es la respuesta q menos fallos me da en el test pero verifica esto... para 144,12,736,27,17, 46,160 esta regresando -1

Comment: @IsraelGonzález, agregué un pequeño hack para que funcione, igual habría que corregir muchas cosas.

Comment: @IsraelGonzález busqué test cases aquí https://www.codewars.com/kata/next-bigger-number-with-the-same-digits/train/javascript y paso todos.

Comment: Gracias Emeeus! Perfecto.. Ahora son 3 respuestas correctas..

Answer (score 3):

Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer, es obtener el número más grande que se puede formar con los números descomponiendo y ordenando los dígitos del número. Si `n` es igual al número entonces ya no se puede formar un número más grande, y retornas `-1`:

```
var v2 = n.toString().split('').sort((a, b) => b - a);
if (n == v2.join(''))
    return -1
```

Si el número aún no es el más grande, entonces lo descompones en otro vector (no puedes usar el primero porque ya está ordenado) y vas rotando sus dígitos empezando desde final, primero cambias el último con el penúltimo, si no es más grande vuelves a cambiar el penúltimo con el antepenúltimo y así hasta que te resulte un número mas grande:

```
var v = n.toString().split('');
i = v.length - 1;
do {
    //en esta parte intercambio el valor de v[i] con el de v[i-1]
    //sin ayuda de una variable auxiliar
    v[i] = v[i - 1] * 1 + v[i] * 1;
    v[i - 1] = v[i] * 1 - v[i - 1] * 1;
    v[i] = v[i] * 1 - v[i - 1] * 1;
    i--;      
} while(v.join('') <= n);
    return v.join('');
```

Y el código al final te quedaría así:

```js
function nextBigger(n) {
    var v2 = n.toString().split('').sort((a, b) => b - a);
    if (n == v2.join(''))
        return -1
    
    var v = n.toString().split('');
    i = v.length - 1;
    do {
      v[i] = v[i - 1] * 1 + v[i] * 1;
      v[i - 1] = v[i] * 1 - v[i - 1] * 1;
      v[i] = v[i] * 1 - v[i - 1] * 1;
      i--;      
    } while(v.join('') <= n);
    return v.join('');
}

console.log(nextBigger(5));
console.log(nextBigger(321));
console.log(nextBigger(513));
console.log(nextBigger(9219));
console.log(nextBigger(123));
console.log(nextBigger(2063));
console.log(nextBigger(1497));
```

Hasta donde alcance a hacer las pruebas funciona bien.

Comment: Gracias @erika_chan muy buena esa parte de intercambiar los digitos, yo encontre como hacerla, estoy tratando de entenderla ahora.. pero pasa lo siguiente cuando los numeros son muy grandes me regresa NaN y con algunos falla la conversion Ej: **20141:** regresa **21014** y deberia ser  **20411**; **1308686**: regresa **1360868** deberia ser **1308866** prueba con **1451, 5257921, 5259127, 1234567890 regresan NaN** me parece que en el primer caso sucede pq estos numeros tienen digitos repetidos

Comment: @IsraelGonzález ok voy a tratar de mejorar mi respuesta luego que me de  tiempo

Answer (score 3):

Encontrar el número más grande posible con ciertos dígitos es tan sencillo como ordernar los números de mayor a menor:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#value');
const out= document.querySelector('#response');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  out.value= input.value.split('').sort((a,b)=> (+b)-(+a)).join('');
});
```

```html
<input id="value"/>
<input id="response" />
```

Pero lo que queremos es hacer el cambio para encontrar el **mínimo número mayor**, con lo que tendremos que ver qué números hay que intercambiar, desde las unidades con las decenas en adelante:

Dado un número de n dígitos, el dígito en la posición n-1 son las unidades.

- Si el número en las decenas (n-2) es menor, con intercambiarlo nos vale.

  ```
  1123 -> 1132
  ```
- Si no, pasamos a comparar con centenas... pero ya tenemos que reordenar los números que quedan *a la derecha* de menor a mayor

  ```
  1132 -> 1231
  ```
- Si no, pasamos a comparar con miles... y nos pasa lo mismo, hay que reordenar los números restantes:

  ```
  21321 -> 22113
  ```

Por tanto, ya vemos un patrón: intentar poner un dígito más grande en una columna que no sea la unidad, dejando los números a la izquierda sin tocar y a la derecha ordenados de menor a mayor:

```js
let numeros=[
  '100032321', //100033122
  4321,  // -1
  12,    //21
  899999, //989999
  '9786543210000', //9800001234567
  '59884848459853', //5988 48484 83559
  4537530,
  98083994
];

function siguiente(n) {
  //Por si nos pasan un número, nos aseguramos que trabajamos con un string
  n = String(n).split(''); 
  let i = 1;
  while( (+n[n.length - i]) <= (+n[n.length - (i + 1)]) && i < n.length) {  
    i++;
  }
  
  if (i >= n.length) {
    return -1;
  }
  i++;
  const izq = n.slice(0,n.length - i); // se quedará igual
  const der = n.slice(n.length - i);
  const first = der.shift(); //sacamos el elemento a mover
  der.sort((a,b) => a - b); //ordenamos
  //encontramos el más pequeño mayor que el elemento a mover
  const indexNewFirst = der.findIndex(a => +a > +first); 
  //los intercambiamos
  const newFirst = der[indexNewFirst];
  der[indexNewFirst] = first;
  
  return izq.concat(newFirst, der).join('');
}

console.log(numeros.map(siguiente));
```

Como puedes ver, la ejecución es inmediata incluso para números muy grandes porque trabaja con arrays de caracteres, ordenándolos, con lo que la complejidad es **n(Log n)** siendo **n** la cantidad de dígitos

Comment: Gracias Pablo Lozano sucede que falla para algunos numeros grandes 
 pienso que sea por la cantidad de dijitos repetidos ej: `59884848459853 => 59884848493558` deberia ser `59884848483559`; para `4537530 => 4570335` deberia ser 4550337; para `98083994 => 98089349` deberia ser `98084399`...

Comment: He visto el fallo, ahora lo arreglo

Comment: Creo que ya esa arreglado... en lugar de usar el número más grande de la derecha, busco el más pequeño que sea mayor que el existente

Comment: Pablo genial! era eso pasa todos los test...

Answer (score 1):

Había borrado mi anterior respuesta porque no estaba cerca de un ordenador para arreglarlo y los resultados que arrojaban eran erróneos. Aquí te dejo una nueva solución, que analizando ahora el código de @PabloLozano hace prácticamente lo mismo y mirando su implementación lo más probable es que la de él sea más [eficiente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia_algor%C3%ADtmica) que la que te estoy brindando.

De cualquier manera, creo que cualquiera de las dos soluciones podría pasar tu test, porque cuentan con una complejidad mucho más baja que situar ciclos anidados.

```js
const nextBigger = (n) => {
  
  const array = `${n}`.split('');
  let big = 0;
  let index;

  for (index = array.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    if (array[index] < big) break;
    big = array[index];
  }

  if (index < 0) return -1;

  const last = array.slice(index);
  
  const next = last.reduce((a, d, i) => {
    if ((d < a[0] && d > last[0]) || d > a[0]) a = [d, i];
    return a;
  }, [last[0], 0]);
  
  [last[0], last[next[1]]] = [last[next[1]], last[0]];
  
  return +[...array.slice(0, index), last[0], ...last.slice(1).sort()].join('');

};

const tests = [513, 2017, 987654321, 414, 1234, 4235, 4321, 69510, 1234567908, 37546227, 59884848459853, 4537530, 98083994];

tests.forEach(n => console.log(`${n} => ${ nextBigger(n) }`));
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta... para 513 regresa -1 y deberia ser 531,  para 2017 regresa 7120 y deberia ser  2071 para 414 esta tmb regresando -1 y deberia ser 441

Comment: No había pensado en esos casos, ahora no tengo ordenador cerca, lo miro en un rato.

Comment: @IsraelGonzález, he variado la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias! ElChiniNet pasa todos los test

Comment: Me alegro @IsraelGonzález