# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un array en JSON JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

hola señores tengo un array así:

```
arr = [ 'carne', 'pollo' ];
```

necesito pasarlo como individual así:

```
{

"nombre:" "carne" ,

}

{

"nombre:" "pollo" ,

}
```

**IMPORTANTE:**
los necesito sin que estén encerrados en los **[ ]**  osea manejarlos en distintas variables asi:

```
{"nombre:" "carne"} {"nombre:" "pollo"}
```

Comment: los necesito sin que estén encerrados en los [ ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que se muestre como quieres puedes tener una cadena y luego recorres el array agregando la cadena en el formato que esperas así:

```js
var arr = [ 'carne', 'pollo' ];
var cad=[];

for(i in arr)
  cad.push('{0: "nombre: '+arr[i]+'"}');

console.log(cad.join(''));

console.log(cad[0]);
```

Comment: Hola, probablemente te han votado negativo por responder una pregunta donde el OP no intento nada, o por que el problema es muy simple y no se deben preguntar y responder cierta clase de preguntas como indica [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), aunque también creo que es injusto, +1 para compensar.

Comment: el codigo de aprendiz esta casi perfecto pero  necesito que en vez de que me retorne asi: {
0: "nombre: carne" ,
1: "nombre: pollo"
} me retorne asi: {0: "nombre: carne"} {0: "nombre: pollo"}

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo :)

Comment: de nada @alejogon y soy nueva, que te hace pensar que see mongo? ┐(´•_•`)┌

Comment: como seria el console.log para consultar solo 1?

Comment: @alejogon volvi a modificar mi respuesta para que tambien puedas mostrar todos o solo uno.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener los valores deseados para componer los objetos por medio de su índice

De este modo:

```
let datos = [ 'carne', 'pollo' ]

let valor1 = datos[0]
let valor2 = datos[1]

console.log({"clave 0": valor1})
console.log({"clave 0": valor2})
```

**Explicación**

- Asignamos a 2 variables por separado cada uno de los valores del vector deseados por medio de su índice
- De modo que la primer variable solo almacene carne y la segunda variable almacene pollo
- Componemos una estructura de `objeto` en el console.log, tomando a la variable y asignando una clave 0 para ambos casos.

De este modo:

```
console.log({"clave 0": valor1})
console.log({"clave 0": valor2})
```

Teniendo una salida como esta

```
[object Object] {
  clave 0: "carne"
}
[object Object] {
  clave 0: "pollo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer uso de [Asignación por destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment),

**Ejemplo sencillo**

```
var foo = ["uno", "dos", "tres"];

// sin destructuración
var uno  = foo[0];
var dos  = foo[1];
var tres = foo[2]; // asignación en tres lineas

// con destructuración
var [uno, dos, tres] = foo; // asignación en una sola linea
```

de esta manera se tienen las tres variables con cada uno de los tres valores

Answer (score 0):

Si nos ceñimos al texto de la pregunta en el sentido de que cada elemento quede:

> **en distintas variables**

no se para que pueda ser útil, pero la forma de crear variables dinámicamente podría ser logrado haciendo algo como esto:

```js
const arr = ['carne', 'pollo'];

arr.forEach((e, i) => {

  eval(`variable${i}={"nombre":"${e}"}`);

});

console.log(variable0);
console.log(variable1);
```

El uso de `eval` es potencialmente peligroso, mas info en esta pregunta de [SO inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).

Comment: Hola colega, esta pregunta es muy básica y ya esta resuelta, creo que podría ser mas interesante hallar una respuesta a otras preguntas como esta por ejemplo : [Mejorar tiempo de la funcion Siguiente mayor numero entero con los mismos digitos Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298834/mejorar-tiempo-de-la-funcion-siguiente-mayor-numero-entero-con-los-mismos-digito)

Comment: @the-breaker gracias a este comentario estuve bastante para poner una solución a esa pregunta.

Comment: Si, ese si era un problema de verdad.